# Offline Map tile options

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm working on a project to have a map of an area 3 by 3 miles visible offline with zoom levels of 15 to 19.
I downloaded the required osm tiles to ship with the bundle and the app is working near enough as I wish. But I see the problem of retina screens needing 512 by 512 tiles. (Is this obligatory?)

I had an idea of arranging for the user to download the required tiles when they have an internet connection to store them for later use.
Am I right in thinking the device would download the retina tiles if required?

The problem there is I can't find any swift tutorial on that subject.
Another problem is I seem to remember seeing a post that I can't find now, saying that as from 16 July Mapquest is stopping providing tile downloads.
If this is so, what other options remain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Maperitive` for downloading the required map files.
You will get complete information here at [Maperitive](http://maperitive.net/).

This is what I used for downloading map files for my android application.
I Hope this helps you. If so I'm happy to help you, but for caching tiles during network availability and storing it for later use, in Swift I'm unable to help you, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for that lead. I'd glossed over Maperitive in the many solutions I'd considered. I managed to download 256 tile and 512 tiles and in 8bits to keep down the total size to 30Mo.
My code to load the tiles is
     let urlTemplate = baseURL.stringByAppendingString("osmm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png/")
Any idea how to load the retina tile when needed?

Comment: i'm sorry i don't know how to load the retina tiles